# C++ reverse string recursion

Tags: c++, string, recursion

I am trying to recursively reverse a string. If `str1 == "hello"`, I want `str1` to become `"olleh"`. 
In my recursive function, I am trying to copy the first character into a temporary variable, pass the string recursively and append the contents of the temporary variable to the end of the returned string. So far, this is my code,

```
# include <iostream>
# include <string.h>
using namespace std;

string string_reverse(string) ;

int main ()
{
    string str1 = "hello";

    cout << string_reverse(str1) << endl;

    return 0;
}

string string_reverse(string str1)
{
    if (str1.length() == 1)
    { return str1;}
    else
        string temp;
        temp.assign(str1, 0, 1);
        str1.erase(0, 1);
        string_reverse(str1);
        return str1.append(temp);
}
```

However, I am getting an error saying `temp` was not declared within the scope.

Comment: If you use an editor that automatically indents your code, you probably would have seen the problem immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a `{` and a `}` -- without them, your else clause is just that one line `string temp;`.

Using an editor that reflows your code automatically can help you see such things.

Answer (score 1):

You need curly braces around your `else` clause.