# C++: Reverse a string using recursion

Tags: c++, string, c++11, recursion

I'm trying to **modify a string passing it by reference by reversing** it
 ex: word dolphin to that it is nihplod using **recurssion only.**
I can't add any more parameters to the function of modify its header.
My output right now is **od** instead of **dolphin**, I think its only doing the last two letters, I honestly don't know why. Any thing that I should change? Here's my code.

```
void reverse(string &word) {
    if (word.length() == 1 || word.length() == 0) {
        if (word.length() == 1) {
            word = word;
        }
        else if (word.length() == 0) {
            word = "nothing to reverse";
        }
    }
    else {
        string temp;
        if (temp.length() == 0) {
            temp = "";
            temp = temp+word.substr(word.length() - 1, 1);
            word.pop_back();
            if (word.length() == 0) {
                word = temp;
            }
            else if (word.length() == 1) {
                //temp = temp + word.substr(word.length() - 1, 1);
                temp = temp + word;
                word.pop_back();
                word = temp;
            }
            else {
                reverse(word);
            }
        }
        else {
            temp = temp + word.substr(word.length() - 1, 1);
            word.pop_back();
            if (word.length() == 0) {
                word = temp;
            }
            else if (word.length() == 1) {
                //temp = temp + word.substr(word.length() - 1, 1);
                temp = temp + word;
                word.pop_back();
                word = temp;
            }
            else {
                reverse(temp);
            }

        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Have you stepped through your logic using a pencil and some paper? And compared it with the execution of your program using a debugger? You should then find where the variables and code flow diverge and you'll know where the bug is, no?

Comment: Why does it need to be recursive?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [C++ reverse string recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21446706/c-reverse-string-recursion)

Comment: You should also do a cleanup of your code: the `else` side of `if (temp.length() == 0)` never executes, for example. Also, when you're writing a recursive function, you should let the base case (the non-recursive case) do the checking - you basically have duplicate code checking if the word length is 0 or 1 in both your base case and your recursive case, when, if you write your base case cleverly, you can just call `reverse(word)` without worrying about the word length.

Comment: @Rodolfo I'm trying to learn recursion, so this is one of the assignments.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I have everything on my whiteboard. I'm afraid is not a matter of comparing the theory to the execution, it might be just some misunderstanding from my part on how recursion works. But thank you, I'll double check.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky that is to check so it doesn't do recursion again. The first two are supposed to be to check if the word is one character or 0 (when entered), so it doesn't go and execute the rest of the code. Thank you for the else part, I did not notice that!

Comment: @huskypanda Why not start out with a 3 letter word, like "cat" instead of "dolphin"?. Then you could more easily follow where your logic is failing.

Comment: Well, if you remove the checks right before the recursive call, you will have one more layer of recursion, but your code will be cleaner and easier to understand/debug. I recommend you read a recursion tutorial such as [this one](https://www.cs.utah.edu/~germain/PPS/Topics/recursion.html) to learn more about what good recursion looks like.

Comment: @NiayeshIsky Thank you for that tutorial, it explains it way better and more detailed!

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Yes, that is a better approach. Thanks for your suggestion!

Answer (score 0):

Algorithm is this:

- If the string length is less than 2, just return
- strip off the first and last chars of the word to create a substring
- recursively call `reverse` on your substring
- After returning from the recursion, prefix the original "last char" and postfix the original "first char" to finish the string

Here you go:

```
void reverse(string& word)
{
    size_t len = word.size();

    if (len < 2)
    {
        return;
    }

    char first = word[0];
    char last = word[len - 1];
    string inner;

    if (len > 2)
    {
        inner = word.substr(1, len - 2);
        reverse(inner);
    }
    word = last + inner + first;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This makes more sense and is waaaay shorter than my solution, plus I just realized that .size() and .length() are the same thing, so thanks for that too!

Answer (score 0):

A non-recursive way of achieving the same thing could be:

```
void reverseString(std::string& input)
{
    const size_t inputStringLength = input.size();
    for (size_t index = 0; index < inputStringLength/2; ++index)
    {
        // swap the character at "index" position with the character at "inputStringLength - index - 1" position
        input[index] ^= input[inputStringLength - index - 1] ^= input[index] ^= input[inputStringLength - index - 1];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void rev_recv(std::string& s, int from, int to) {
    if (from >= to) return;
    rev_recv(s, from + 1, to - 1);
    std::swap(s[from], s[to]);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
void reverse(string &word) 
{
    string temp = word;
    if(temp.length != 0)
    {
       cout << temp.at(temp.length()-1);
       reverse(temp.erase(temp.length()-1));
    }
    else
       cout << "\ndone\n";
}
```

This will print in reverse and not modify the original string that was passed in.
If you want the original string modified, just remove the `temp` variable.

Comment: Actually, your code has two issues: 1) `temp.length` needs brackets to make it a function call. 2) Removing the `temp` variable will modify the original string, but it just will just empty it, not store the reversed string in it (see [this test code](http://cpp.sh/9hef)).

Comment: Yeah I realized that he wants to modify the original to become reversed after I posted this code. Yeah I do realize it empties it